# Materials different in blender 2.8 than in 2.79

Tags: materials

so i just downloaded blender 2.8 and all my materials look different than what they did in 2.79 i know materials are different in 2.8 but i want them to look like they did in 2.79 first picture has different face but everything else is the same i want to make the second one in blender 2.8 look like the first one in blender 2.79
[image]

[image]

Comment: figured it out dont know how to delete this

Comment: Instead of deleting this, post an answer below instead, so others can learn and benefit from what you've found out